# Generating strings of length l with hamming distance d

Tags: javascript

I’m working on a variation of the Motif Search Problem and have hit a block on the logic of one of the subparts.

The problem is:

You have the alphabet — `['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']`

Now, you are given an array of strings made of these alphabets with length L and are given a hamming distance D.

For example, if we take `L=3`, `d=2` and are given the array ["ACT","TGC","GTA"].

For each string in the array, we must generate strings of the same length (3 in this case) using the alphabet which have a hamming distance of `d`. The hamming distance `d` means that the final string will only have d edits (two if d = 2) as compared to the original string.

So if we take the example of ACT from the array, we must generate GTT, AAG, CGT and so on.
And I want to store these generated strings in a list.

A recursive function that breaks down the string seems like the most efficient way to do it but I’m having trouble implementing it. Any ideas for the logic explained with code/pseudocode? I need to be able to extend this problem to L = 15 and d = 5.

Example of Hamming distance d = 1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can get you started. It doesn't handle creating strings of different length than the source. Perhaps you could add that.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(alphabet, str, prefix, i, d){
  if (d == 0)
    return [prefix + str.substr(i)];
    
  let words = [];
  
  for (let j=0; j<alphabet.length; j++){
    if (alphabet[j] != str[i]) 
      words = words.concat(
        f(alphabet, str, prefix + alphabet[j], i+1, d-1)
      );
  }

  if (str.length - i > d)
    words = words.concat(
      f(alphabet, str, prefix + str[i], i+1, d)
    )
  
  return words;
}

const alphabet = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'];

const strs = ["ACT", "TGC", "GTA"];

for (let str of strs){
  console.log(str);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(f(alphabet, str, '', 0, 2)));
  console.log('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the following analogy to solve this problem: if suppose you have to change two symbols at the same time and a substring of length 15. First, make a set of all combinations of two indexes ranging from 0 to 14. In python you can do that using itertool function. Second, create all the combinations of two symbol from the choice of symbols you have, "gatc" in this case. Next, iterate over every index combination (i: a set of two numbers ranging from anywhere between 0-14)  and iterate over symbols combination (j: a set of two symbols) in nested fashion. In iteration, If any of the char, corresponding to the indexes i selected, is not equivalent to combination of symbol j in correspondance then we can replace those indexes with j. In this way, you can obtain all the neighbours of a string. The time complexity of this algo is O(n).

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Python Function** to generate Hamming strings of distance d from a particular string.

```py
# Function to generate strings with hamming distance d
def gen_ham_strings(alphabets, string, prefix, i, d):
    
    # Base Case
    if d == 0:
        return [prefix + string[i:]]
    
    words = []
    
    for j in range(len(alphabets)):
        if alphabets[j] != string[i]:
            words += gen_ham_strings(alphabets, string, prefix + alphabets[j], i+1, d-1)
    
    if len(string) - i > d:
        words += gen_ham_strings(alphabets, string, prefix + string[i], i+1, d)
    
    return words
```